# Not able to upgrade from cassandra 2.0.3 to 2.0.9

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I used the same steps i had enquired for upgrading cassandra from 2.0.3 to 2.0.7 to upgrade it to 2.0.9.

[Regarding upgrade from 2.0.3 to 2.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190115/regarding-upgrade-from-2-0-3-to-2-0-7)

But i am facing some problem with respect to gossiping.

My scenario:

X is running on 2.0.3

Y is started now in 2.0.9

I had copied the data files from Y's 2.0.3 data directory to Y's 2.0.9 data directory. Made the changes as specified in the link above.

Now , when i start 2.0.9 , i get the following stuff in logs of 2.0.9

> **INFO [HANDSHAKE-/172.20.9.23] 2014-08-19 14:37:28,606 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 386) Handshaking version with
>   **/X****  INFO [FlushWriter:1] 2014-08-19 14:37:28,626 Memtable.java (line 403) Completed flushing
>   /home/sas/apache-cassandra-2.0.9/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-564-Data.db (5279 bytes) for commitlog position
>   ReplayPosition(segmentId=1408439241980, position=355252)  **INFO
>   [main] 2014-08-19 14:37:28,638 StorageService.java (line 1558) Node /Y
>   state jump to normal  INFO [main] 2014-08-19 14:37:28,653
>   CassandraDaemon.java (line 543) Waiting for gossip to settle before
>   accepting client requests...**  INFO [main] 2014-08-19 14:37:36,654
>   CassandraDaemon.java (line 575) No gossip backlog; proceeding

It doesnt throw any error in logs too. I can clearly see that the problem is with gossiping but not able to find why .

**nodetool status returns "?" for load of X. 
Y seems to be up with 2.0.9 but X is not working with Y. 
Moreover , Y is not detected in X.**

What am i doing wrong in the upgrade? Any idea to make this work?

Comment: can you post the output from nodetool gossipinfo

Comment: As i had stated, the problem was with gossiping. gossipinfo didnt find the other node(which is configured to be in another DC)